# Removing the header without removing page numbering

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering, fancyhdr

I'm using documentclass article. I want the page number to appear on the top-right corner and heading on the top-left corner. Though I want page numbering in every page, I don't want the heading on the very first page. When I'm using `\pagestyle{fancy}` and `\lhead{My Header}`, I'm getting the header on the desired position. However, the page number is in the bottom and there is a horizontal line under the header which I don't want. On the other hand when I'm using `\pagestyle{headings}`, I'm getting the page numbering correct but no title.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{headings}

\begin{document}
This gives the page number on top-right, but no title in any page
\end{document}
```

and

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{My header} 

\begin{document}
This gives the header on top-left, but with a 
horizontal bar and the page number in bottom-middle
\end{document}
```

How to put the header on top-left and the page number on top-right without any horizontal line? Also, I don't want the header on the first page, I just want the page number on the first page.

Edit: Here are two photos of the page I'm trying to reproduce.
[image][image]

Comment: The answers show you what you need.  Be forewarned that `\maketitle` ends with its own `\thispagestyle`, so your `\thispagestyle` would need to come after it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following example should meet your requirements. It defines a `firstpage` page style with nothing but the page number at the top right, and it sets the `fancy` page style to produce some text ("My header", following your example) on the top left, the page number on the top right, and nothing on the foot of the page.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\lhead{My header}
\rhead{\thepage}
\cfoot{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancypagestyle{firstpage}{%
    \lhead{}
    \rhead{\thepage}
    \cfoot{}
}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{firstpage}
This is the first page, without header on the left, and with the page number at the right.
\newpage
This is another page, with a header on the left and the page number on the right.
\end{document}
```

This is the head of the first page of the output:
[image]

and this is the head of the second page of the output:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Hi Abdul Muhaymin and Welcome to TeX-SE.

Assuming you really only want to remove the section name -- which is given with the command `\leftmark` at the MWE below -- then you can use the `\thispagestyle{plain}` at the very beginning of your document.

**If** you want something like "don't show *this*/*that* every first page of section/chapter", **then** a different approach is needed.

`\fancyhf{}` removes the bottom page number bothering you.

`\fancypagestyle{plain}` defines how the style will behave, in this case, `plain`.

`\pagestyle{headings}` defines the style to the whole document.

`\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}` is a very cheap method to remove the line you mentioned.

A MWE with some options to `fancypagestyle` and some figures follow.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{% change predefined style 
    \fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields 
    \fancyhead[R]{\thepage}
    %   \fancyhead[RO,LE]{\thepage} % Right Odd, Left Even => Outside
%   \fancyhead[L]{\leftmark} % except the left top corner 
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % remove line between header and main text 
}
\pagestyle{headings} % fancy, headings, myheadings

\begin{document}
\section{ONE DIMENSIONAL}
\thispagestyle{plain}
\lipsum[1-10]
\section{1D Harmonic}
\lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```

The very first page doesn't have the section name on the header.
[image]

The following pages have.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi! @FHZ Thanks for the warm welcome. Both of the answers here work perfectly for my purpose. I actually didn't add any sections. It's just a header for all pages except the very first one. Your code is certainly useful for more general cases. So I chose vincent's answer as accepted because it addresses my problem specifically. But this answer also give a more organized approach and I appreciate that.

Comment: You are welcome @AbdulMuhaymin. The answers are basically the same, we just post them at the same time. Two different people came to the same solution, which is a good sign of robustness. ;)