# fancyhdr - Chapter name disappears

Tags: sectioning, header-footer, chapters, fancyhdr

I´m currently working on my thesis and would like to change the header with the help of fandyhdr.
In order to remove *CHAPTER* in front of my chapter-names I used this command:

```
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
```

It worked out, but the section-name in the header is now capitalized. I tried also to renew the command of `\sectionmark`, but then the chapter-name has disappeared.

Here I have a minimal example of my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[a4paper,width=150mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm]{geometry}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

%Remove Chapter in front of chapter-name
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}    

%Tried to de-capitalize section-name
%\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markboth{\thechapter.\ #1}{}}

\begin{document}

\chapter{chapterOne}

\section{sectionOne}

\section{sectionTwo}

\chapter{chapterTwo}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi @nomeal and welcome to TeX-SE. Please verify if [this question and answers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/528739/140133) satisfy your needs.

Comment: Hi @FHZ, unfortunately this question doesn´t satisfy my needs, because I would like to have the chapter-name, as well as the section-name as a header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use \markright for the section, not \markboth.

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[a4paper,width=150mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm]{geometry}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

%Remove Chapter in front of chapter-name
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}

%Tried to de-capitalize section-name
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection.\ #1}}

\begin{document}

\chapter{chapterOne}

\section{sectionOne}

\section{sectionTwo}
\newpage abc\newpage abc
\chapter{chapterTwo}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you very much!